# display dictionary file inside for loop in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following dictionary:

```
d = {'21': 'test1', '11': 'test2'}

 {% with '18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28' as list_upper %}
 {% for x in list_upper.split %}

     {% if x in dental_position %}
     <input type="text" placeholder = "{{ x }}" class="form-control" name="tooth[]" value="{{display dict.value here}}">
     {% else %}<input type="text" placeholder = "{{ x }}" class="form-control" name="tooth[]">
     {% endif%} 


 {% endfor %}
```

I want to display the `d[value]` inside input text value attribute when values from `d[key]` is found in `list_upper`

How can I call `{% if d.keys in x %}` in django template?

Comment: You need a django template [tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) here. It will make this problem fairly trivial.

Comment: and is there a reason you didn't define `list_upper` in your context? You wouldn't have to to the crazy coding in your template that you're doing for your for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a tag file like this:

```
# tags.py
def is_dict_key(key, d):
   return key in d

def get_dict_value(d, key):
  try:
      return d[key]
  except KeyError as e:
      print(e)
      return None
```

Assuming your view passes in context that looks like this:

```
context = { 
    'dental_position': {21: 'test1', 11: 'test2'} 
    'list_upper': [18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
}
```

Then in your template you can do this:

```
{% load tags %} 
{% for x in list_upper %}

     {% if x|is_dict_key:dental_position %}
       <input type="text" placeholder = "{{ x }}" class="form-control" name="tooth[]" value="{{dental_position|get_dict_value:x}}">
     {% else %}
       <input type="text" placeholder = "{{ x }}" class="form-control" name="tooth[]">
     {% endif%} 


 {% endfor %}
```

I'm doing this all from my head so there might be a formatting or syntax bug in there somewhere but following the documentation I linked earlier this should get you to where you need to be.

Comment: This is my first time to use template tags. Thank you for your immediate response. It works for me.

Comment: @CarlosFabiera Glad it worked. I plugged it into a test project of my own and realized I needed to make a few changes to make it play nicely. I assume you had to do the same xD