# Django nested dictionary to display in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
dict = {
'https://i.redd.it/4d87ifm2mch01.jpg': 'https://reddit.com/7yv1d8', 
'https://i.redd.it/ru0bq0jpr9h01.jpg': 'https://reddit.com/7ys0l3',
 'videos': {'https://gfycat.com/ifr/selfassuredinfinitehochstettersfrog'},..
}
```

`'videos'` stores values as a set so i wont have duplicate urls and it's convenient.
But i faced a problem, how can I display the nested dictionary in templates?
I have it like that for now

```
{% for keys,values in data.items%}

{% for i,j in keys.items %}
<iframe src='{{j}}' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' allowfullscreen width='300' height='300'></iframe>


<a class="thumbnail" href="{{values}}"><img src="{{keys}}" width="100px" height="66px" border="1" /><span><img src="{{keys}}" /><br />whatever.</span></a>
<br />
```

I want the `'videos'` values to be stored in the `<iframe>` and others as an image.

Comment: You need to use django tags like I explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47818325/3715522

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `.items` on `keys` will probably raise an error because they are strings and I don't know what `data` holds, however assuming it is sent to template in your view like:

```
return render(request, "myapp/index.html", {"data": dict})
```

then you can check if `key` [equals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal-and-ifnotequal) to `"videos"`, and iterate through the set as well:

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
  {% ifequal key "videos" %}
  <iframe ...>
    {% for url in value %}
      <a class="thumbnail" href="{{ url }}">{{ url }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  </iframe>
  {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry for late resposne, I could only lay my hands on it today, but unfortunately the template raises an error, i just commented out my code and tried copy pasting into my template. My views.py returns exactly the way you pointed out.
`Invalid block tag on line 56: 'endifequal', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'.`
Just to point out, it does display images if I only include them in an `<img>` tag and ignore the `<igrame>` tag

Comment: @nexla are you sure you copied the above snippet correctly? As far as i can see from it, I don't think you can get an error saying there is a missing closing tag. Btw, there are 2 `for` loops there. One for iterating through the dictionary, one for iterating through the `videos` set.

Comment: I think the issue is that I am using set in a dictionary and it redirects me to the `value` url.  I tried using different data types, it does indeed work as if a string, however I am gonna have troubles w/ multiple urls i parse, but i'm gonna figure something out. So yes, your answer was correct and it was my fault :) Thank you !

Comment: Actually, I managed to keep it as a set.
What i did,  I passed `' '.join(set object)` and voila it was a valid url, for those of people who might have the same issue in the future :)